# Is there a ros package that can provide GUI for other ros nodes?

Tags: ros, gui, rqt, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a camera and multiple sensors mounted on my robot. And I will write ros nodes for all of them. But is there a ROS package that can provide GUI to show data got my camera and sensors together?

I use Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS electric. So I think package rqt doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51273/is-there-a-ros-package-that-can-provide-gui-for-other-ros-nodes?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Direct solution to your problem could be that since `ROS` is distributed system, you could receive messages from your robot (as long as they're published as `ROS` format) on different computers that run `fuerte` or higher where `rqt` is available.

---

Regarding `rqt` as @joq suggests, I actually tried using it on `electric` recently and my answer is no it's impossible/not worth trying.

I used `fuerte-devel` branch (that is the oldest branch afaik, and also doesn't use `catkin` to build) of [rqt](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt) which also requires [qt_gui_core](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core) and [python_qt_binding](https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding) with same branch names on github. When I run `rosmake qt_gui_core` I got the following error which seems to depend on a `pluginlib`'s function that might not exist in `electric`. So, if you dare to workaround even further, `rqt` may or may not work. I'm curious.

Used `Ubuntu Lucid, electric`

```
/home/rosuserian/ROS/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp/recursive_plugin_provider.cpp:68:   instantiated from here
/home/rosuserian/ROS/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/include/qt_gui_cpp/ros_pluginlib_plugin_provider.h:237: error: ‘class pluginlib::ClassLoader<qt_gui_cpp::PluginProvider>’ has no member named ‘createInstance’
```

---

(Added on Jan 12) Another answer based on comments on @alfa_80's answer, is again, `rqt`. You can open `RViz` and `dynamic_reconfigure`'s GUI called `rqt_reconfigure` at the same time on a single window. Using `Groovy` is ideal though.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-03**:
Thanks for the useful information, Isaac.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-03**:
BTW, I do not recommend mixing different ROS distros in the same ROS graph. In some cases that may work, but not in general.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-03**:
Agreed. Unless mixing distros is the only solution..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to try   [`rviz`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz) if you are on `electric`.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2013-01-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-01**:
Hi alfa, rviz is mainly for 3D visualization right? I don't need to plot the data gathered by kinect and laser in 3D. What I need is just a GUI that has several panels to show the information gathered by camera, battery power and temperature sensor.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-01**:
It would be better if ros dynamic reconfigure GUI can integrate with it.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2013-01-03**:
I've limited skill on this, perhaps you can refer to joq's answer, that's better.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For future reference, the [recommended solution would be rqt](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt), but that package is not currently available on Electric.

I have no idea how difficult a back-port to Electric would be. You might consider [contacting the author on github](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt) to see if it seems feasible and whether he is willing to accept such a patch.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2